# Shear on the event horizon of the black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

In terms of spin coefficients, shear is defined as

$$\sigma=(m_a)(m_b)(\nabla_al^b)$$

where $m,l$ denotes null tetrad vectors. I came across the following paragraph from [one of Stephen Hawking's papers](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01645515.pdf):

> What happens is
> that the perturbation produces tidal forces which distort the horizon.
> If the black hole is not rotating, the distortion of an element of the
> horizon will be constant in time and the shear will be zero. If the black
> hole is rotating, however, distortion will be periodic in time and so there
> will be shear.

So distortion directly does not mean shear? In a nonrotating black hole, though distortion is constant in time, still, distortion is there, then why shear is zero?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: Shear is not the only type of distortion, there are vorticity and divergence associated to null rays. Even other spin connections also have some interpretations in terms of curvature.